# Can verb "produce" have indirect object?

Tags: grammar

Can verb "produce" have indirect object? I heard such lines "I first produced me pistol and I then produced me rapier" In the song "Whiskey in a Jar"

Comment: The pistol and the rapier are direct objects!

Comment: From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/produce): **5** VERB If you produce an object from somewhere, you show it or bring it out so that it can be seen. Similarly [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/produce) says **C1** 'transitive verb'.

Comment: As @KateBunting says they are direct objects - but you may be confused my "me pistol", "me rapier". In cockney English - as well as some other dialects "my" is often rendered in speech as "me".

Comment: @WS2 - including  Irish (the song is by The Dubliners).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. I guess a lot of dialects in the British Isles use the possessive "me".

Comment: @WS2 - On a whim, just now I went to Youtube for the 1973 [Thin Lizzy version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WDSY8Kaf6o) which I like more than the Dubliners' version. Thin Lizzy were, if you forgive the expression, shit-hot. I found that something seemed to reached across five decades and brought tears to my eyes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - the greatest rock song ever recorded without a bass line ;) [Listen again if you didn't spot it first time. Vocals went down with the main band recording. They never went back to put Phil's bass on it.]

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Perhaps they are middle-class and know their possessive pronouns.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "produce" is normally transitive. It nearly always has a direct object. This sense is similar to "show" See the [dictionary defintion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/produce#:%7E:text=to%20take%20an,his%20pocket.)

> to take an object from somewhere so that people can see it:
>
> > *One of the men suddenly produced a gun from his pocket.*

The verb produce does not normally have an indirect object.
Note that "me" is not the indirect object, it is a dialect variant of "my". In standard English this would be ""I first produced *my* pistol".  The direct object is the noun phrase "me(my) pistol".